# Widget with internal uiBinder code

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I would like to create widget where you can inject some part of uiBinder code.
For instance

```
<c:MyWidget title="Title text" type="SOME_TYPE">
    <g:Button ... />
    <g:HTMLPanel ... > ... </g:HTMLPanel>   
</c:MyWidget>
```

I addition MyWidget has itself uiBinder code like bellow:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="...">SOME HEADER</g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="mainBody"/>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="...">SOME FOOTER</g:HTMLPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

and into main body I would like to inject code which is wrapped via

What I did so far is :

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite implements HasSafeHtml {
...
    private static MyWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyWidgetUiBinder.class);
    interface MyWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidget> {}

...

@Override
public void setHTML(String html) {
    modalBody.getElement().setInnerHTML(html);
    this.innerContent = html;
}
```

but it doesn't parse generated code like buttons or htmlPanels I can only insert pure html.

also I did sth like above

```
public class MyWidget extends HTMLPanel {
private static MyWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyWidgetUiBinder.class);
interface MyWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidget> {}

@UiConstructor
public ModalWindow(Type type, String title, String html) {
    super(html);
...
```

but I even don't know how to capture code form from first code listing in this question. I'm getting error "missing required attribute(s): html:"

Does somebody has some idea how to build such component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to implement [HasWidgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasWidgets.html) interface. In the `add()` method insert widgets to `mainBody` panel.

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite implements HasWidgets {

    private static MyWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyWidgetUiBinder.class);

    interface MyWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidget> {}

    @UiField
    HTMLPanel mainBody;

    public MyWidget() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Widget w) {
        mainBody.add(w);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        mainBody.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Widget> iterator() {
        return mainBody.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Widget w) {
        return mainBody.remove(w);
    }
}
```

Tested, it works.

Comment: Correct - you cannot implement _both_ HasHtml/HasSafeHtml and HasWidgets/HasOneWidget, uibinder will just get confused and pick the first it sees. HTMLPanel only pulls it off by cheating, there is specific code in uibinder's internals to handle it.